# Android Lollipop Material Design Overflow Menu Icon color

Tags: java, android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I try the new Material Design on a Nexus 7 and have the following strange behaviour. The Overflow Menu Icon has a different color on the first app launch.

I changed the `android:textColorPrimary` color and read this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html).

1. First App launch:[image: first app launch]
2. Second App launch:[image]

As you see the color of the primary text color is not set on the first launch. It is only set if i press the home button and relaunch the app. Here is my `styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#FF4444</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#CC0000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Can someone explain, why that behaviour occurs?

I set `android:minSdkVersion="21"` and don't want to use support libraries.

Comment: Just use Light.DarkActionBar instead of Light. It handles changing the theme against which the action bar content is inflated and will save you a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: Hey @alanv, I tried your suggestion, it makes the text color of both "Material Demo" and the dots in right become white. How to make them all dark?

Comment: Oh, I missed that you're trying to make them all dark. Just using the Light theme should already accomplish this. Are you using appcompat or changing anything else in the theme?

Comment: That is just a workaround for white or black text colors. If I use a different color the problem still exists. I would like to know how to fix that.

Comment: please post the toolbar layout code

Comment: @SagiLow What do you mean with toolbar layout code?

Comment: you must have a `toolbar` `view` (where the theme you showed is applied), usually it is a layout, but the `view` code is enough

Comment: Are you using appcompat?

Comment: Please, read this: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/. You need to use appcompat-v7 lib. I would recommend you to use android studio + gradle and add "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'" to your dependencies. Then just follow the chris banes steps. You do need a Toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem when running a `PreferenceActivity` which cannot use appcompat-v7 library on a `LOLLIPOP` device. When this activity is opened for the first time the overflow icon is always white completely ignoring `android:textColorPrimary` and `android:colorControlNormal`. Subsequent runs or orientation changes however result in proper coloring.

I created a gist which will help you mitigate this. The code binds a global layout observer to the toolbar and when it finds an overflow icon it replaces it and unbinds the observer. So don't use it in places where you don't expect an overflow icon because the observer won't get unbound in that case.

Link to gist: https://gist.github.com/consp1racy/4b640679de553fdb3046

Answer (score 1):

Just add the secondary text color for the options menu, i.e.:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_color</item>
```

In some circumstances the secondary color is set to the primary color. I don't know yet why.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help.

Comment: You wrote that you're using the support libraries. Have you tried using the appcompat themes from the android-support-v7 library? If you are targeting minimum android versions below 21 you'll probably should have a look on it. However, this is just a side note. Are you using other additional styles or themes for the actionbar? The dots belong to the action overflow and has its own design: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Comment: update: Now I removed all support libraries and set `android:minSdkVersion="21"`.

Answer (score 1):

Add these items too:

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
```

If this didn't help, then try this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

This would works for `Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. I am wondering why I am the only one that has that problem. It is so easy to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use material design in pre-21 devices you need to extend `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` theme. To do that, you need to add compile `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0` as a dependency of your project, this way you will be able to use the Toolbar in your layout.

Then define your theme in **values/themes.xml:**:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_color</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_color</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
    colorControlHighlight & colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
</style>
```

and your the toolbar in your **layout/my_activity.xml**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

You have optional attrs to define the theme and popupTheme as well:

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

Chris Banes wrote a good article about this that you should read https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

I read on the comments of the questions that you are using eclipse, I highly recommend to use android studio + gradle and no eclipse.

Comment: I don't want to use it on pre 21 devices and I don't want to use support libraries.

Comment: Then why do u say that in the comments that you are defining min sdk 18?

Comment: In a newer comment I said that I raised the API level to `android:minSdkVersion="21"` to be sure that the API level/ support library is not the problem. Moreover I use in my question `android:Theme.Material.Light` and not `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. I will delete the comment so that it is not confusing.

Comment: Try the same I said but without appcompat and should work. Same procress with noactionbar theme and the toolbar in your xml.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"`to the Toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

overflow menu icon will be white now :)

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me.  Using the .Dark attribute will make my overflow menu icon white!  Perfect!